# preg_replace with replacement function

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do you use `preg_replace` with a function as the replacement parameter? I'm getting an error with this code.

```
function getInfo($id,$slot){
  if(!$id){ return '<b>Error</b> Id Not Returned. Please contact support@site.com for more information.'; }
  $mm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
  $mma = mysql_fetch_assoc($mm);
  $p = $mma[$slot];
  return $p;
  //return $id; <- Debug (Returns ID given)
}
$post = preg_replace(
  "/\[CallName]([^]]+)\[\/CallName\]/", 
  getInfo('\\1',"fullname"), 
  $post
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` modifer is now [**deprecated**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) in favor of **[preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)**.

Sample usage:

```
$x = 'abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop';

$x = preg_replace_callback(
  '/-(.)/', //pattern
  function($matches) { //callback
    return strtoupper($matches[1]);
  }, 
  $x //subject
);

echo $x; //abcdEfgHijkLmnop
```

Comment: @Jake I just stumbled across this randomly and thought I might help out future viewers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `e` modifier **(PREG_REPLACE_EVAL)** in preg_replace function, this modifier is needed to evaluate replacement string as PHP code. It should be like this:

```
$post = preg_replace('~\[CallName\]([^]]+)\[/CallName\]~e', 'getInfo("$1", "fullname")', $post);
```

See [this manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for for details.