# Preg Replace - E Modifier

Tags: php, mysql, function, preg-replace

```
$strpost_a = preg_replace("/\[CallName]([^]]+)\[\/CallName\]/e", getInfo('\\1',"fullname"), $strpost_a);
```

I always get this in return:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\-site\files\index\stream.php(88) : regexp code on line 1
Fatal error: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Failed evaluating code: James -LastName Removed- in C:\wamp\www\-site-\files\index\stream.php on line 88
```

Comment: I'm assuming the line you posted is 88...

Comment: did you copy preg_replace from somewhere? like a website or a word document? you might have some special character with it, remove the white space around the equal sign and try again

Comment: Didn't you ask this about an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024710/preg-replace-with-functions? May I know the reasons for duplicate posting of same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to properly escape your brackets:

```
"/\[CallName\]([^]]+)\[\/CallName\]/e"
```

Second, when using the `e` modifier your replacement still needs to be a string. However it is a string that is *evaluated* as PHP code after backreferences are substituted. Try the following:

```
"getInfo('\\1', 'fullname')"
```

Check out the docs for more detail on the [e modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) must always be a string. Using the `/e` flag doesn't change that. And the second parameter simply should be a string *consisting* of code:

```
$strpost_a = preg_replace(
                 "/\[CallName]([^]]+)\[\/CallName\]/e",
                 'getInfo("\\1","fullname")',
                 $strpost_a
             );
```

The string `'getInfo("\\1","fullname")'` will *then* be evaluated. If you do not enclose it in quotes here, it will not be executed by `preg_replace`, but beforehand. That's why you got the error message.

(It's sometimes more suitable to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), but would likely require a specific `getInfo_fullname` in your case.)